Is there a fast way to write Pinyin on Gboard?
Is there a fast way to write Pinyin on Gboard, which makes the diverse spelling rules and rules for the tone mark and apostrophes user-friendly through suggestions on top of the keyboard as we are used for other language systems?
I know of course Pinyin is almost never written out unless for educational purposes - and these are exactly those I opt for.
Maybe there's a downloadable in-app feature or any other add-on I don't know. But currently, I have to insert everything character by character and fiddle with the right tone marks by pressing a character long and choosing between the options which pop up - which is not a solution in the long run.
Since I have seen Chinese people write Pinyin fast, I'm pretty sure such a feature exists on Chinese phones, but I want it on my phone as well.
